# What would this icon look like if it was drawn in an Isometric View as opposed to a Perspective View?

Tags: icon, perspective, isometric

I can't wrap my head around this grid icon.

[image: Grid Perspective]

What would it look like if it was an Isometric drawing? Would it look like a regular rectangle? Maybe, something like this?

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: If you read this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isometric_projection and start to think like it says you will know that both of your images can well be isometric projections of shapes in  the 3D space. The upper one may for ex. present a flat non-rectangular grating. There are infinitely different shapes in 3D which have the same isometrically projected 2d images. The lower one can well present a flat rectangular grating, which is rotated in the 3D space to the position where the surface normal points towards the observer of the isometric projection.

Comment: (continued) The next image is an isometric view which contains two 3D objects which are otherwise identical, but colors are different.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0wTo.png The thing which makes the view isometric is the viewing direction  compared to X, Y and Z axles of the coordinate system. The grey grille lies still in its original position where I happened to build it. The green copy of it is shifted a little +  rotated 2 times 45 degrees to generate the same projected profile as your image 1.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you have done your homework about understanding what an isometric projection is. Allow me to explain it.

The most common projection we use is an orthogonal view. That is how we draw houses as kids. One axis horizontal and one vertical. 90° apart. We can draw a uniform grid using those axis and put your image over it. It measures 3x2.

[image]

An isometric view has 3 axis, each 120° apart. We can draw a grid representing a wall and put the image we had on the orthogonal plane measuring the same amount of squares 3x2. But we also could think that plane was originally a floor, not a wall.

[image]

That is your image in an isometric projection.